# Are value types immutable by definition?

Tags: c#, .net, immutability, value-type

I frequently read that `struct`s should be immutable - aren't they by definition?

Do you consider `int` to be immutable?

```
int i = 0;
i = i + 123;
```

Seems okay - we get a new `int` and assign it back to `i`. What about this?

```
i++;
```

Okay, we can think of it as a shortcut.

```
i = i + 1;
```

What about the `struct` `Point`?

```
Point p = new Point(1, 2);
p.Offset(3, 4);
```

Does this really mutate the point `(1, 2)`? Shouldn't we think of it as a shortcut for the following with `Point.Offset()` returning a new point?

```
p = p.Offset(3, 4);
```

The background of this thought is this - how can a value type with no identity be mutable? You have to look at it at least twice to determine if it changed. But how can you do this without an identity?

I don't want to complicate reasoning about this by considering `ref` parameters and boxing. I am also aware that `p = p.Offset(3, 4);` expresses immutability much better than `p.Offset(3, 4);` does. But the question remains - aren't value types immutable by definition?

**UPDATE**

I think there are at least two concepts involved - the mutability of a variable or field and the mutability of the value of a variable.

```
public class Foo
{
    private Point point;
    private readonly Point readOnlyPoint;

    public Foo()
    {
        this.point = new Point(1, 2);
        this.readOnlyPoint = new Point(1, 2);
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        this.point = new Point(1, 2);
        this.readOnlyPoint = new Point(1, 2); // Does not compile.

        this.point.Offset(3, 4); // Is now (4, 6).
        this.readOnlyPoint.Offset(3, 4); // Is still (1, 2).
    }
}
```

In the example we have to fields - a mutable one and a immutable one. Because a value type field contains the whole value, a value type stored in a immutable field must be immutable, too. I am still quite suprised by the result - I did not exspect the readonly field to remain unmodified.

Variables (besides constants) are allways mutable, hence they imply no restriction on the mutability of value types.

---

The answer seems not to be that straight forward so I will rephrase the question.

Given the following.

```
public struct Foo
{
    public void DoStuff(whatEverArgumentsYouLike)
    {
        // Do what ever you like to do.
    }

    // Put in everything you like - fields, constants, methods, properties ...
}
```

Can you give a completed version of `Foo` and an usage example - that may include `ref` parameters and boxing - so that it is not possible to rewrite all occurences of

```
foo.DoStuff(whatEverArgumentsYouLike);
```

with

```
foo = foo.DoStuff(whatEverArgumentsYouLike);
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> An object is immutable if its state
> doesn’t change once the object has
> been created.

Short answer: No, value types are not immutable by definition. **Both structs and classes can be either mutable or immutable.** All four combinations are possible. If a struct or class has non-readonly public fields, public properties with setters, or methods which set private fields, it is mutable because you can change its state without creating a new instance of that type.

---

Long answer: First of all, the question of immutability only applies to structs or classes with fields or properties. The most basic types (numbers, strings, and null) are inherently immutable because there is nothing (field/property) to change about them. A 5 is a 5 is a 5. Any operation on the 5 only returns another immutable value.

You can create mutable structs such as `System.Drawing.Point`. Both `X` and `Y` have setters which modify the struct's fields:

```
Point p = new Point(0, 0);
p.X = 5;
// we modify the struct through property setter X
// still the same Point instance, but its state has changed
// it's property X is now 5
```

Some people seem to confuse immutablity with the fact that value types are passed by value (hence their name) and not by reference.

```
void Main()
{
    Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
    SetX(p1, 5);
    Console.WriteLine(p1.ToString());
}

void SetX(Point p2, int value)
{
    p2.X = value;
}
```

In this case `Console.WriteLine()` writes "`{X=0,Y=0}`". Here `p1` was not modified because `SetX()` modified `p2` which is a *copy* of `p1`.  This happens because `p1` is a *value type*, not because it is *immutable* (it isn't).

Why *should* value types be immutable? Lots of reasons... See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil). Mostly it's because mutable value types lead to all sorts of not-so-obvious bugs. In the above example the programmer might have expected `p1` to be `(5, 0)` after calling `SetX()`. Or imagine sorting by a value which can later change. Then your sorted collection will no longer be sorted as expected. The same goes for dictionaries and hashes. The [Fabulous Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) ([blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/)) has written a [whole series about immutability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability) and why he believes it's the future of C#. [Here's one of his examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/mutating-readonly-structs) that lets you "modify" a read-only variable.

---

UPDATE: your example with:

```
this.readOnlyPoint.Offset(3, 4); // Is still (1, 2).
```

is exactly the what Lippert referred to in his post about modifying read-only variables. `Offset(3,4)` actually modified a `Point`, but it was a *copy* of `readOnlyPoint`, and it was never assigned to anything, so it's lost.

And *that* is why mutable value types are evil: They let you *think* you are modifying something, when sometimes you are actually modifying a copy, which leads to unexpected bugs. If `Point` was immutable, `Offset()` would have to return a new `Point`, and you would not have been able to assign it to `readOnlyPoint`. And then you go *"Oh right, it's read-only for a reason. Why was I trying to change it? Good thing the compiler stopped me now."*

---

UPDATE: About your rephrased request... I think I know what you're getting at. In a way, you can "think" of structs as being *internally* immutable, that modifying a struct is that same as replacing it with a modified copy. It might even be what the CLR does internally in memory, for all I know. (That's how flash memory works. You cannot edit just a few bytes, you need to read a whole block of kilobytes into memory, modify the few you want, and write the whole block back.) However, even if they were "internally immutable", that is an implementation detail and for us developers as users of structs (their interface or API, if you will), they *can* be changed. We can't ignore that fact and "think of them as immutable".

In a comment you said "you cannot have a reference to the value of field or variable". You are assuming that every struct variable has a different copy, such that modifying one copy does not affect the others. That is not entirely true. The lines marked below are not replaceable if...

```
interface IFoo { DoStuff(); }
struct Foo : IFoo { /* ... */ }

IFoo otherFoo = new Foo();
IFoo foo = otherFoo;
foo.DoStuff(whatEverArgumentsYouLike); // line #1
foo = foo.DoStuff(whatEverArgumentsYouLike); // line #2
```

Lines #1 and #2 do not have the same results... Why? Because `foo` and `otherFoo` refer to the *same boxed instance* of Foo. Whatever is changed in `foo` in line #1 reflects in `otherFoo`. Line #2 replaces `foo` with a new value and does nothing to `otherFoo` (assuming that `DoStuff()` returns a new `IFoo` instance and does not modify `foo` itself).

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo(); // creates first instance
Foo foo2 = foo1; // create a copy (2nd instance)
IFoo foo3 = foo2; // no copy here! foo2 and foo3 refer to same instance
```

Modifying `foo1` won't affect `foo2` or `foo3`. Modifying `foo2` will reflect in `foo3`, but not in `foo1`. Modifying `foo3` will reflect in `foo2` but not in `foo1`.

Confusing? Stick to immutable value types and you eliminate the urge of modifying any of them.

---

UPDATE: fixed typo in first code sample

Comment: I added this comment to several answers before. I could rewrite p.X = 5; as p = p.SetX(5);. If I can always do this - the value type semantics may allow this, but I don't know for sure - I could consider the struct to be immutable or equivalent to an immutable struct. So I rephrased the question - can I always do this transformation? If yes, this implies that structs are immutable because I can rewrite them in a way that makes the immutability obviouse.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not sure I follow you. If you can do p.X = 5 the type is mutable. If p2 = p1.SetX(5) does not change p1, and there is no way of changing p1, then it is immutable. Note that p = p.SetX(5) is replacing the value of p with a new one, not modifying the original value.

Comment: You are absolutly right. And because p is a value type and you cannot have a reference to it, it should not matter if you modify the value stored in p or replace it with a modified version. If you find an example where this matters - maybe something involving ref parameters, boxing, or something I haven't even thought about (currently thinking about value type properties) - than I am wrong and structs are mutable. If I can always transform myStruct.ChangeStuff() into myStruct = myStruct.ChangeStuff(), than I can consider structs to be immutable.

Comment: I think I finally understood what you mean! It was all in "p is a value type and you cannot have a reference to it", but you *can*, through boxing and interfaces. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Internal immutability: This isn't an implementation detail - if you have a "mutable" struct with myStruct.ChangeState(), you can redesign the interface to myStruct = myStruct.GetCloneWithChangedState() making the struct "immutable". Both versions have the exactly same behavior using a different interface - so why should I call one version mutabe and one immutable?

Boxing: I considered boxing a struct and then passing the object around, but all methods will operate on distinct unboxed values, hence the calls will not modify the shared value.

Comment: Interface boxing: That is the true answer. Great! Value types are not immutable (I should better say "behave like immutable types") because you can share a reference to them by interface boxing. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielBrückner: Even so-called "immutable" value types can be shown not to be immutable, if the storage location in which they are stored is overwritten while they are being acted upon.  For example, if has an instance of `KeyValuePair<Foo,Bar>` stored in some field, and the `ToString` method of `Foo` replaces the contents of that field with a new instance, the string returned will contain the `ToString` value of the old `Foo` concatenated with that of the new `Bar`.

Comment: clever use of interface there, its one of the few uses of interface i have seen that is proving interface to be very useful, (talking from an average coder point of view).

Comment: The part `IFoo foo3 = foo2; // no copy here! foo2 and foo3 refer to same instance` is incorrect. Changes to `foo2` will NOT reflect through `foo3`. For `interface IFoo { int Val { get; } }  struct Foo : IFoo { public int v; public int Val => v; }` you get `Debug.Assert(foo2.v != foo3.Val);`

Answer (score 12):

Mutability and value types are two separate things.

Defining a type as a value type, indicates that the runtime will copy the values instead of a reference to the runtime. Mutability, on the other hand, depends on the implementation, and each class can implement it as it wants.

Comment: I am aware of that, but the question is if being a value type implies being immutable.

Comment: It does not imply it, since it's up to the user to implement the inmutability. You can have a Point class that is inmutable, or implement is as mutable.

Comment: I still think you cannot. Could you give an example where modifing a struct with myStruct.DoStuuf() cannot be explained as myStruct = myStruct.DoStuff()?

Comment: This happens because you are reusing the variable myStruct.
If DoStuff modifies the same instance, then the assignment doesn't do anything (it copies over the same). If DoStuff yields another modified instance, you assign it, and overwrite the old myStruct memory space with it.

Comment: This is what I mean - you can explain modifying a struct with overwriting a struct with another struct returned from a method. Hence you could consider structs to be immutable. The above is obviously not true for reference types.

Comment: If myStruct were a reference to a reference type (the sole reference in the system), the same would happen... You will have a newer object, referenced by the same variable.

Answer (score 8):

You can write structs that are mutable, but it is best practice to make value types immutable.

For instance DateTime always creates new instances when doing any operation. Point is mutable and can be changed.

To answer your question: No, they are not immutable by definition, it depends on the case if they should be mutable or not. For instance, if they should serve as dictionary keys, they should be immutable.

Comment: You can create a simple struct like struct Foo { public int Bar; }. The question is not if you can do this, but if Foo is mutable or not.

Comment: The System.Drawing.Point struct, for example, isn't immutable.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that there are any mutable structs in the framework. Correct my answer, thanks.

Comment: I can rewrite point.X = 42; as point = point.SetX(42); and if I can always do this, I might consider the Point struct immutable even if the interface does not show this very well.

Answer (score 5):

If you take your logic far enough, then *all* types are immutable. When you modify a reference type, you could argue that you're really writing a new object to the same address, rather than modifying anything.

Or you could argue that everything is mutable, in any language, because occasionally memory that had previously been used for one thing, will be overwritten by another.

With enough abstractions, and ignoring enough language features, you can get to any conclusion you like.

And that misses the point. According to .NET spec, value types are mutable. You can modify it.

```
int i = 0;
Console.WriteLine(i); // will print 0, so here, i is 0
++i;
Console.WriteLine(i); // will print 1, so here, i is 1
```

but it is still the same i. The variable `i` is only declared once. Anything that happens to it after this declaration is a modification.

In something like a functional language with immutable variables, this would not be legal. The ++i would not be possible. Once a variable has been declared, it has a fixed value.

In .NET, that is not the case, there is nothing to stop me from modifying the `i` after it's been declared.

After thinking about it a bit more, here's another example that might be better:

```
struct S {
  public S(int i) { this.i = i == 43 ? 0 : i; }
  private int i;
  public void set(int i) { 
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    this.i = i;
  }
}

void Foo {
  var s = new S(42); // Create an instance of S, internally storing the value 42
  s.set(43); // What happens here?
}
```

On the last line, according to your logic, we could say that we actually construct a new object, and overwrite the old one with that value.
But that's not possible! To construct a new object, the compiler has to set the `i` variable to 42. But it's private! It is only accessible through a user-defined constructor, which explicitly disallows the value 43 (setting it to 0 instead), and then through our `set` method, which has a nasty side-effect. The compiler has no way of *just* creating a new object with the values it likes. The only way in which `s.i` can be set to 43  is by *modifying* the current object by calling `set()`. The compiler can't just do that, because it would change the behavior of the program (it would print to the console)

So for all structs to be immutable, the compiler would have to cheat and break the rules of the language. And of course, if we're willing to break the rules, we can prove anything. I could prove that all integers are equal too, or that defining a new class will cause your computer to catch fire.
As long as we stay within the rules of the language, structs are mutable.

Comment: Maybe the best answer up to now. But I think this are two concepts - mutability of a variable and mutability of the value of a variable. Going to think about it... +1

Comment: I have rewritten it ... I modified your example a bit - if I introduced something you didn't want, please undo this, but I believe you really wanted to set the field to 43.

Comment: Actually, the "set" function was wrong. It should obviously just set the private "i" field and nothing else. No return values.

Comment: I removed your example again and modified my post a bit to make my point clearer. Perhaps you misread my example because of the above error?
What I wanted to show is that if structs are immutable, the compiler would have to instantiated a new S object to overwrite the one I explicitly created on the first line in Foo(). But there is no way for the compiler to create an an instance of S where the "i" field = 43, so it can't just arbitrarily create new instances. It has to modify the existing one instead, because that's the only way 'i' can ever be set to 43.

Comment: I forgot to add something to my edit - I am not talking about letting the compiler rewrite the code. I was just talking about manual redesigin of the struct and its interface, hence the big differences between your example and my rewritten version.

Comment: But what does that prove? Yes, we can always rewrite our code to use immutable structs, but that doesn't mean every struct *is* immutable. :)

Comment: No, there is a huge difference between a mutable reference type and a value type.  If I have two variables of type `StringBuilder` and I copy one to another, any changes I make to the target of the first (e.g. `var1.Append("Fred")`) will affect the second.  That is nowhere near equivalent to creating a new instance and making the first variable point to it (e.g. `var1 = new StringBuilder(var1.ToString + "Fred")`).

Comment: I never said a value type was the same as a mutable reference. I merely said that value types are mutable. `struct S { public int i = 42; } S s; s.i = 43;` I have modified a member of my `S` struct. That would not be possible if value types were immutable.

Comment: @jalf: Value types have semantics which are distinct from those of mutable reference types or immutable reference types.  If I have a private field of type `StringBuilder`, which holds a reference to a `StringBuilder` instance, and someone else with a reference to that same `StringBuilder` instance changes the first character, the first character of by `StringBuilder` instance will change without anything having been written to my field.  By contrast, if I have a field of type `Point`, the only way its `X` property will ever change is if something writes to that field.

Comment: @jalf: In many ways, structs behave more like immutable classes than mutable ones (a string is immutable, but code which can write a `string` field called `foo` can make the first character of `foo` be "X" by storing a reference to a string starting with "X").  The biggest differences are that that struct methods receive the underlying storage location by reference, rather than by value, updating a struct field is less costly than creating a new instance, and the threading semantics of structs are different from those of classes.

Comment: @supercat: how exactly is an object not mutable **if you can update the data in its memory location during its lifetime**? This is an absurd argument. Value types *behave* like they're mutable: I can assign new values to them, I can modify their fields. That means they are mutable. If I have an object containing a field, and I can modify the value of that field, *then the object containing the field is mutable*.

Comment: Strings are immutable because, given a given string, I can never change any of its fields. A *reference* to a string is mutable because I can change which string it points to. A struct which contains a public field is mutable, because I can, without creating a new struct to take its place, modify that public field, *changing the value of the struct*

Comment: @jalf: The behavior of a struct is in many ways closer to that of an immutable class object than a mutable one.  If a storage location with is mutable, then normally-implemented properties of that *storage location* will be able to change, regardless of whether the storage location is struct or class; mutable or immutable.  If the storage location is immutable, then its properties can only change if the storage location holds a mutable class (or the properties access a mutable class defined elsewhere).

Comment: @jalf: The principle benefit of using immutable classes is that the properties of a storage location of an immutable class type can only be changed by code which can write to that storage location.  That same guarantee applies just as well to structs (whether or not they allow piecewise mutation), which is to say that whether or not structs are mutable, *they share the most useful characteristic of immutable classes*.

Comment: @supercat: what? You're talking nonsense. You're saying that the principle benefit of immutable classes is that they're mutable? That (some) code can change their storage? Does not compute! An immutable class is one **which cannot be mutated**. End of story. A string is immutable because given a string instance, you **cannot modify it**. You can swap it out for a different instance, but you can never ever modify it. That's what immutable **means**. You can decide to refer to a different instance (by assigning it to the string reference), but the string itself is immutable

Comment: For value types to be immutable, the same would have to be true. Given an instance of a struct, it must be impossible to change it. You could argue that if I do something like `int i = 0; i = 1` then I'm not mutating an int, I'm creating a new one. That's not really what the CLR actually *does*, but never mind that. The effect is the same whether or not we consider the int to be mutated. However, if you define a struct with one or more modifiable fields, then the outer struct is *not* replaced with a different instance when you update one of its fields. Thus **it is mutable**

Comment: Have you ever worked in a language where variables are immutable? Because it really really feels like you don't actually know what the word *means*

Comment: @jalf: Immutable classes would be pretty useless if references to them couldn't be stored in mutable storage locations.  The benefit of an immutable class like `string` is that the semantic content of a storage location (e.g. field `foo`) of type `string` can only change if the *storage location itself does*.  If `foo` initially holds a reference to string "Fred", then `foo.Length` will equal 4.  If I perform the statement `foo = "George"`, then `foo.Length` will equal 5.  Code which can change `foo`--and only code which can change `foo`--can change `foo.Length`.

Comment: @jalf: By contrast, if I have a field `Bar` of type `StringBuilder`, then unless it holds a reference to an instance I created myself and haven't shared with outside code, I have no way of knowing when `Bar.Length` might change.  Outside code will be able to change Bar.Length, *whether or not it has any access to `Bar`*, without giving my code any notice or warning.  That's a level of mutability which structs, fortunately do not have (except to the extent that they contain mutable-class-type fields).

Comment: Did you notice the word **except**. You are saying that **by definition**, structs are immutable, even though you yourself know of an **exception** which contradicts it? I think we're done here. I'm sorry, I can't argue with that logic. Why don't we say that value types are, by definition, sandwiches, even though they're actually purple?

Answer (score 4):

> I don't want to complicate reasoning
>   about this by considering `ref`
>   parameters and boxing. I am also aware
>   that `p = p.Offset(3, 4);` expresses
>   immutability much better than
>   `p.Offset(3, 4);` does. But the
>   question remains - aren't value types
>   immutable by definition?

Well, then you're not really operating in the real world, are you?  In practice, the propensity of value types to make copies of themselves as they move between functions meshes well with immutability, but they aren't actually immutable unless you make them immutable, since, as you pointed out, you can use references to them just like anything else.

Comment: Of course, this is quite a theoretical question and the thing with ref and boxing - I didn't yet figure that out completly. I tend to say ref is no problem because you obtain a reference to the variable, not to the contained value. Boxing seems a bit harder and I am still thinking about it.

Comment: Your argument for ref doesn't make sense. Yes, you obtain a reference to it, but the value you're modifying is still a value-type.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're talking about in regard to ref either.  Here is the object: I have obtained a reference to it.  I can change it, which changes the values associated with that very same object in memory.  How is this "immutable" in any sense of the word?  It's acting just like any reference type at this point.

Comment: Given the method static void Bar(ref int arg) { arg = 42; } and int foo = 1; Bar(foo);. This will modify foo, but it should surly not indicate that int is mutable. This is because you obtain a reference to the variable foo, not the contained int value.

Comment: @daniel: if you don't really understand references then you don't understand the real issues of mutability.  have a little experience in lowlevel languages (C) and you'll see the problems. then check a sane hilevel language (Scheme and Lua are great for this), and you'll se how immutability helps.

Comment: I have written code in many languages from Assembler to Prolog. If you think I missed something, give an example for the question I am going to add to my original question.

Answer (score 4):

> aren't value types immutable by definition?

No they're not: if you look at the `System.Drawing.Point` struct for example, it has a setter as well as a getter on its `X` property.

However it may be true to say that all value types *should* be defined with immutable APIs.

Comment: Yes, it has the setter, but I could rewrite point.X = 42; as point = point.SetX(42) - the question is if this is always possible. If yes, you could consider the struct to be immutable (but with an interface that does not express this immutability very well).

Comment: If the purpose of a type is to encapsulate a fixed collection of independent variables (such as the coordinates of a point), the optimal realization is a struct with exposed public fields (which will behave as a fixed collection of independent variables).  One can achieve such behavior awkwardly with an immutable class, and can code a struct in such fashion as to be just as awkward to use as the immutable class, but if one's goal is to encapsulate a fixed set of variables fastened together with duct type, why not use a data type which is implemented, and behaves, exactly like what's desired?

Comment: @supercat The main problem is structs with a set property, which lets you do something like `point.X += 3` which doesn't do what you expect; whereas an API which requires you to say `point.SetX(point.X + 3)` is not so error-prone.

Comment: @ChrisW: My present philosophy is that structs should when practical *either* try to emulate an immutable class, *or* should be a collection of exposed public fields, without any methods that write `this`.  APIs should avoid struct methods which write `this`, since compilers will generate bogus code when such methods are used on read-only structures.  The API you give is the most problematic form; I think you meant to say something like `point = point.WithX(point.X+3);` or `Point2d.SetX(ref point, point.x+3);`

Comment: @ChrisW: Basically, as I figure it, an exposed-field struct doesn't really "encapsulate" anything; in cases where encapsulation would be helpful, that's a bad thing, but in some cases encapsulation is a hindrance.  If a struct contains no state other than a set of values that can be read without side effects, and if an instance with any combination of those values can be created without side effects, those facts will fully define the semantics of the struct--it will be equivalent to an exposed-field struct with fields of those types.  So why make it awkward for people to use it as what it is?

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion is that if you have a reference type that should act like a value type it's a good idea to make it immutable.  One of the key differences between value types and reference types is that a change made through one name on a ref type can show up in the other name.  This doesn't happen with value types:

```
public class foo
{
    public int x;
}

public struct bar
{
    public int x;
}


public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foo a = new foo();
        bar b = new bar();

        a.x = 1;
        b.x = 1;

        foo a2 = a;
        bar b2 = b;

        a.x = 2;
        b.x = 2;

        Console.WriteLine( "a2.x == {0}", a2.x);
        Console.WriteLine( "b2.x == {0}", b2.x);
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
a2.x == 2
b2.x == 1
```

Now, if you have a type that you'd like to have value semantics, but don't want to actually make it a value type  - maybe because the storage it requires is too much or whatever, you should consider that immutability is part of the design.  With an immutable ref type, any change made to an existing reference produces a new object instead of change the existing one, so you get the value type's behavior that whatever value you're holding cannot be changed through some other name.

Of course the System.String class is a prime example of such behavior.

Comment: That point is clear - reference types with value type semmantics must or at least should be designed immutable. From your statement "[...] This doesn't happen with value types: [...]" I conclude that you tend to agree on my conclusion - value types are immutable by definition because you cannot obtain a reference to a value, right?

Comment: No - value types are not immutable by definition.  In my example above, the `b.x = 2;` statement changes `b` - it just doesn't also change `b2`.  That's a key difference between value types and ref types.  I suppose you could look at it as if `b` got an entirely new object with a new value when it's changed, but that's not what's happening and I see nothing useful coming out of thinking about it that way.

Comment: Now you got my point. I am currently thinking about myStruct.DoStuff(); rewritten as myStruct = myStruct.DoStuff(); because this makes the immutability of the struct obviously. My question could be rephrased - can you find an example where the mentioned transformation cannot be done or will not work?

Comment: I see no technical problem with it.

Comment: "can you find an example...?" Yes, if b and b2 where both declared as the interface IBar.

Comment: @DanielBrückner: An operation like `Threading.Interlocked.Increment(MyStruct.SomeField);` cannot be emulated by any statement of the form `MyStruct = something(MyStruct)`.  It could, however, be emulated via `MyStructType.BumpField(ref MyStruct);`.

Answer (score 2):

Last year I wrote a blog post regarding the problems you can run into by not making structs 
 immutable.

[The full post can be read here](http://www.blog.activa.be/2008/05/25/TheProblemsWithValueTypes.aspx)

This is an example of how things can go horribly wrong:

```
//Struct declaration:

struct MyStruct
{
  public int Value = 0;

  public void Update(int i) { Value = i; }
}
```

Code sample:

```
MyStruct[] list = new MyStruct[5];

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
  Console.Write(list[i].Value + " ");
Console.WriteLine();

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
  list[i].Update(i+1);

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
  Console.Write(list[i].Value + " ");
Console.WriteLine();
```

The output of this code is:

```
0 0 0 0 0
1 2 3 4 5
```

Now let's do the same, but substitute the array for a generic `List<>`:

```
List<MyStruct> list = new List<MyStruct>(new MyStruct[5]); 

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
  Console.Write(list[i].Value + " ");
Console.WriteLine();

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
  list[i].Update(i+1);

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
  Console.Write(list[i].Value + " ");
Console.WriteLine();
```

The output is:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

The explanation is very simple. No, it's not boxing/unboxing...

When accessing elements from an array, the runtime will get the array elements directly, so the Update() method works on the array item itself. This means that the structs itself in the array are updated.

In the second example, we used a generic `List<>`. What happens when we access a specific element? Well, the indexer property is called, which is a method. Value types are always copied when returned by a method, so this is exactly what happens: the list's indexer method retrieves the struct from an internal array and returns it to the caller. Because it concerns a value type, a copy will be made, and the Update() method will be called on the copy, which of course has no effect on the list's original items.

In other words, always make sure your structs are immutable, because you are never sure when a copy will be made. Most of the time it is obvious, but in some cases it can really surprise you...

Comment: The problem is not that mutable structs are evil, but rather that C# does not have a means of indicating what methods will mutate a struct, so that it can forbid their use in read-only contexts.  Compared to promiscuous objects, mutable structs often offer vastly superior semantics.  If I have a struct 'foo', and I call bar1(foo), I can guarantee that 'bar' won't change any of the fields of foo (if some of the fields hold class references, it is of course possible that the targets of those references could be changed).  If I call bar2(ref foo), then bar2() might change foo, but...

Comment: ...any such changes that are going to happen will happen before bar() returns.  By contrast, if I have a class object 'zoo' and I call bar3(zoo), it's possible that bar3() might mutate zoo immediately, or it might store a reference to zoo somewhere that will cause some other thread to mutate it at some arbitrary future time.  That seems much more evil than any problems mutable structs have.  To be sure, .net support for mutable structs has some odd quirks, but those are faults of .net, not the concept of mutable structs.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not. Example:

```
Point p = new Point (3,4);
Point p2 = p;
p.moveTo (5,7);
```

In this example `moveTo()` is an *in-place* operation. It changes the structure which hides behind the reference `p`. You can see that by look at `p2`: It's position will also have changed. With immutable structures, `moveTo()` would have to return a new structure:

```
p = p.moveTo (5,7);
```

Now, `Point` is immutable and when you create a reference to it anywhere in your code, you won't get any surprises. Let's look at `i`:

```
int i = 5;
int j = i;
i = 1;
```

This is different. `i` is not immutable, `5` is. And the second assignment doesn't copy a reference to the structure which contains `i` but it copies the content of `i`. So behind the scenes, something completely different happens: You get a complete copy of the variable instead of only a copy of the address in memory (the reference).

An equivalent with objects would be the copy constructor:

```
Point p = new Point (3,4);
Point p2 = new Point (p);
```

Here, the internal structure of `p` is copied into a new object/structure and `p2` will contain the reference to it. But this is a pretty expensive operation (unlike the integer assignment above) which is why most programming languages make the distinction.

As computers become more powerful and get more memory, this distinction is going to go away because it causes an enormous amount of bugs and problems. In the next generation, there will only be immutable objects, any operation will be protected by a transaction and even an `int` will be a full blown object. Just like garbage collection, it will be a big step forward in program stability, cause a lot of grief in the first few years but it will allow to write dependable software. Today, computers just aren't fast enough for this.

Comment: You said, "Now, Point is immutable etc.", but that's not a good example: Point is *not* immutable.

Comment: You are wrong, p2 will not equal p after the method call p.moveTo(5,7) if Point is a value type.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm right since Point is not a value type in my example. ("in-place operation")

Comment: @ChrisW: It is since there are no methods to modify it in-place.

Comment: To clear up the mess: I missed the ".net". I'm talking about OO languages in general, not .net in particular.

Comment: "This is different. i is not immutable, 5 is." This is a good point. The variable itself is mutable, but not the value of the variable. So against you answer "No, they are not." I still believe they are. Can you give an example where myStruct.DoStuff() cannot be explained as myStruct = myStruct.DoStuff()?

Comment: When myStruct.DoStuff() changes the internal state of the object, anyone holding a reference to that object will be affected. If all methods to the object return a new object, then this internal state can't be changed from outside, making it effective immutable like the "5". In the same way adding 1 to 5 doesn't change the 5.

Comment: That said, I don't know anything about structs in .Net :) So this is just how it works in general.

Comment: Structs in .NET are value types like ints - so you cannot have a reference to the value of field or variable.

Comment: @Daniel: "you cannot have a reference to the value", yes you can, see my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

No, value types are *not* immutable by definition.

First, I should better have asked the question "Do value types behave like immutable types?" instead of asking if they are immutable - I assume this caused a lot of confusion.

```
struct MutableStruct
{
    private int state;

    public MutableStruct(int state) { this.state = state; }

    public void ChangeState() { this.state++; }
}

struct ImmutableStruct
{
    private readonly int state;

    public MutableStruct(int state) { this.state = state; }

    public ImmutableStruct ChangeState()
    {
        return new ImmutableStruct(this.state + 1);
    }
}
```

[To be continued...]

Answer (score 1):

To define whether a type is mutable or immutable, one must define what that "type" is referring to.  When a storage location of reference type is declared, the declaration merely allocates space to hold a reference to an object stored elsewhere; the declaration does not create the actual object in question.  Nonetheless, in most contexts where one talks about particular reference types, one will not be talking about a *storage location which holds a reference*, but rather *the object identified by that reference*.  The fact that one can write to a storage location holding a reference to an object implies in no way that the object itself is mutable.

By contrast, when a storage location of value type is declared, the system will allocate within that storage location nested storage locations for each public or private field held by that value type.  Everything about the value type is held in that storage location.  If one defines a variable `foo` of type `Point` and its two fields, `X` and `Y`, hold 3 and 6 respectively.  If one defines the "instance" of `Point` in `foo` as being the pair of *fields*, that instance will be mutable if and only if `foo` is mutable.  If one defines an instance of `Point` as being the *values* held in those fields (e.g. "3,6"), then such an instance is by definition immutable, since changing one of those fields would cause `Point` to hold a different instance.

I think it is more helpful to think of a value type "instance" as being the fields, rather than the values they hold.  By that definition, any value type stored in a mutable storage location, and for which any non-default value exists, will *always* be mutable, regardless of how it is declared.  A statement `MyPoint = new Point(5,8)` constructs a new instance of `Point`, with fields `X=5` and `Y=8`, and then mutates `MyPoint` by replacing the values in its fields with those of the newly-created `Point`.  Even if a struct provides no way to modify any of its fields outside its constructor, there is no way a struct type can protect an instance from having all of its fields overwritten with the content of another instance.

Incidentally, a simple example where a mutable struct can achieve semantics not achievable via other means: Assuming `myPoints[]` is a single-element array which is accessible to multiple threads, have twenty threads simultaneously execute the code:

```
Threading.Interlocked.Increment(myPoints[0].X);
```

If `myPoints[0].X` starts out equal to zero and twenty threads perform the above code, whether simultaneously or not, `myPoints[0].X` will equal twenty.  If one were to attempt to mimic the above code with:

```
myPoints[0] = new Point(myPoints[0].X + 1, myPoints[0].Y);
```

then if any thread read `myPoints[0].X` between the time another thread read it and wrote back the revised value, the results of the increment would be lost (with the consequence that `myPoints[0].X` could arbitrarily end up with any value between 1 and 20.

Answer (score 0):

Objects/Structs are immutable when they are passed into a function in such a way as the data cannot be changed, and the returned struct is a `new` struct. The classic example is

`String s = "abc";`

`s.toLower();`

if the `toLower` function is written so they a new string is returned that replaces "s", it's immutable, but if the function goes letter by letter replacing the letter inside "s" and never declaring a "new String", it is mutable.