# Equality of two structs in C#

Tags: c#

I look for an equality between two instances of this struct.

```
public struct Serie<T>
{
    T[]         X; 
    double[]    Y;

    public Serie(T[] x, double[] y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Serie<T> && this == (Serie<T>)obj;
    } 
    public static bool operator ==(Serie<T> s1, Serie<T> s2)
    {
        return s1.X == s2.X && s1.Y == s2.Y;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Serie<T> s1, Serie<T> s2)
    {
        return !(s1 == s2);
    }
```

This doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
        double[] xa = { 2, 3 };
        double[] ya = { 1, 2 };
        double[] xb = { 2, 3 };
        double[] yb = { 1, 2 };
        Serie<double> A = new Serie<double>(xa, ya);
        Serie<double> B = new Serie<double>(xb, yb);
        Assert.AreEqual(A, B);
```

Comment: Related post - [Comparing boxed value types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6205029/465053) & [Are value types immutable by definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/868411/465053)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're comparing the array *references* rather than their contents. `ya` and `yb` refer to different arrays. If you want to check the contents of the arrays, you'll have to do so explicitly.

I don't *think* there's anything built into the framework to do that for you, I'm afraid. Something like this should work though:

```
public static bool ArraysEqual<T>(T[] first, T[] second)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(first, second))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (first == null || second == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (first.Length != second.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    IEqualityComparer comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!comparer.Equals(first[i], second[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

As an aside, your structs are sort of mutable in that the array contents can be changed after the struct is created. Do you really need this to be a struct?

EDIT: As Nick mentioned in the comments, you should really override GetHashCode as well. Again, you'll need to get the contents from the arrays (and again, this will cause problems if the arrays get changed afterwards). Similar utility method:

```
public static int GetHashCode<T>(T[] array)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    IEqualityComparer comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    int hash = 17;
    foreach (T item in array)
    {
        hash = hash * 31 + comparer.GetHashCode(item);
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: using LINQ's SequenceEqual() extension method. It can compare array contents.

Comment: @LBushkin: Yes (I should have mentioned that), but it will be somewhat inefficient compared with an implementation which is geared around arrays.

Comment: Possibly, but I tend to prefer clarity over performance, unless there's a measured performance problem. Out of curiosity, what makes you believe `SequenceEquals` would be inefficient?

Comment: +1 I would add that GetHashCode needs to be overridden when overriding Equals and so you will need to hash the arrays (or use a really bad hash code like always returning a constant).

Comment: @LBushkin: Unless it's actually *optimized* for arrays somewhere, it won't have the most efficient paths available to it. Arrays can be pretty heavily optimised. I agree about preferring simplicity in general, but this is a useful utility method to write once and then use in lots of places. @Nick: Good point about GetHashCode; will add that to the answer.

Comment: unlike several of the Linq extension methods SequenceEqual has no special casing for lists or arrays (some special casing for lists will work with arrays as they implement IList<T> by magic).
It doesn't even do the Count optimization if both implement ICollection or IList<T>

Comment: oh and adding my voice to the , this *really* shouldn't be a struct.

Comment: .NET 4 (released after this post) provides structural comparisons. Array and Tuple types implement IStructuralComparable and IStructuralEquatable. The StructuralComparisons class has a default StructuralComparer and StructuralEqualityComparer that provide you with proper compare, equals and gethashcode implementations for arrays and tuples, although for tuples the default equality semantics are structural anyway.

Answer (score 6):

> I don't think there's anything built into the framework to do that for you, I'm afraid

In 4.0, there is:

```
StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(firstArray, secondArray);
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but it would be better if it stood on it's own without quoting another answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should compare the contents of the Array in your Equality logic ...

Also, it is recommended that you implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface on your struct, as this prevents boxing/unboxing issues in some cases.
http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatable-t-you-still-must-override-object-s-equals-and-gethashcode.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The part `s1.Y == s2.Y` tests if they are 2 references to the *same array instance*, not if the contents are equal. So despite the title, this question is actually about equality between array(-reference)s.

Some additional advice: Since you are overloading you [should design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx) `Serie<>` as immutable and because of the embedded array I would make it a class instead of a struct.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `==` performs *reference equality* on arrays - they don't compare the contents of their elements. This basically means that `a1 == a2` will only return true if the exact same *instance* - which isn't what you want, I think..

You need to modify your `operator ==` to compere the contents of the `x` array, not it's reference value.

If you're using .NET 3.5 (with link) you can do:

```
public static bool operator ==(Serie<T> s1, Serie<T> s2)
{
    return ((s1.X == null && s2.X == null) || s1.X.SequenceEquals( s2.X )) 
           && s1.Y == s2.Y;
}
```

If you need to do deep comparison (beyond references), you can supply `SequenceEquals` with a custom `IEqualityComparer` for the type of T.

You probably should also consider implementing the `IEquatable<T>` interface for your struct. It will help your code work better with LINQ and other parts of the .NET framework that perform object comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a private accessor for your struct and use `CollectionAssert`:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void SerieConstructorTest()
{
    double[] xa = { 2, 3 };
    double[] ya = { 1, 2 };
    double[] xb = { 2, 3 };
    double[] yb = { 1, 2 };
    var A = new Serie_Accessor<double>(xa, ya);
    var B = new Serie_Accessor<double>(xb, yb);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(A.X, B.X);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(A.Y, B.Y);
}
```

This code works fine.

References:

- [CollectionAssert.AreEqual Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal(VS.80).aspx)
- [How to create private accessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184796(VS.80).aspx)