# StructuralComparisons Class

Tags: c#, collections, .net-4.0

I want to know what for is StructuralComparisons Class present in System.Collections used and also how is it used?I have no idea how should I use it!! Smallest help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.structuralcomparisons.aspx ?

Comment: Couldn't get it exactly from there!!

Comment: Maybe this example will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042282/equality-of-two-structs-in-c/2042469#2042469

Answer (score -1):

StructuralComparisons is used to compare the structur of two values.

It is used in F# where StructuralComparisons is automaticly implented for every type,
because of that two trees can be compared by just comparing the roots.

Comment: what about C#? It is a collection class in C#!!